# Does Openthread support Application Layer Security like OSCORE?

Tags: openthread

I am starting to use OpenThread in a project to communicate using CoAP protocol. I wanted to know if OpenThread supports OSCORE if I do not want to use DTLS for security.

Answer (score 0):

According [OpenThread DTLS alternatives](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/openthread-users/oscore%7Csort:date/openthread-users/ha2prCQ9FEw/9fEoOE_aCwAJ) at least in 2019 there was no alternative. I'm not sure, why you search for one.

Comment: DTLS is transport layer security which may create overheads of handshaking during communication. I am looking for Application Layer Security for efficiency to be exact. There is OSCORE mechanism for CoAP, however I am not sure if OpenThread already have a support for this or how can somebody implement on top of OpenThread CoAP APIs.

Comment: The required handshakes depends much on your network environment. Using DTLS 1.2 Connection ID lowers significantly the number of handshakes caused by address changes (but I guess, open-thread doesn't use it :-) ). With that, the number of the required handshakes should be similar to the number of "OSCORE key rederivation".